# Displaying views according to screen size

Tags: android, view

When you are displaying views according to dp scale, it means that they are displayed the same physical size at any device... Which means that the display might seem a little emptier at bigger screens right?
Then How do you display views according to the screen sizes?

Comment: read some android docs before asking such questions

Answer (score 0):

For different screen size, Use  different Layout and different image
This linke is good [Supporting Multiple Screens | Android Developers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVppPhpvnKAhXD6HIKHeBTBDQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Fpractices%2Fscreens_support.html&usg=AFQjCNHemvlQ2sNEATp3v6KONvL52P-N7A&sig2=XlGqtSGNVs4KscmTe9R7DQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.bGQ)

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```